# A Method for Creating Cross-Sectional Views of Point Cloud Data in MeshLab

Tags: 3d, point-clouds, meshlab

I have a question.
I am currently working with point cloud data in MeshLab.
Is it possible to create a cross section from point cloud data?
If it is possible, please tell me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Conditional vertex selection" filter, which will select all the points that meet some constraint.

Comment: Thanks. You've saved me again. You are the MeshLab master.